# Collecting data from different sections of multiple excel workbooks and appending it into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have to collect data from different sections of multiple excel workbooks(uniform formatting) and append it to a new workbook. The format is similar to the picture below. I have to collect data from the green and blue sections(not tables) from multiple workbooks and append it like the table in the next picture.
[image]

[image]

I know that this can be done using VBA. Unfortunately, I have never used VBA before. It would be great if someone can provide a generic code or at least point me in the right direction. Also, if this can be done in any other way, please do share.
Thank you
Note: I have a list for hyperlinks for all the workbooks.

Comment: What is the condition for data to be collected? Is it only background color, or something else?

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber: I only need the data values, I have used background color just to highlight different sections for better understanding of the question. Thank you

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I asked for a generic code if it's available out there. I have also mentioned "point me in the right direction", it would have been great if you had added the direction in the comment. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA crash course for your project. All the code should work but I am writing it right now so it's untested. I'll try to explain the best as I can line by line in this example code. You can reference all the data you need by cell, row, column or range. I would recommend assigning all the data to an array then writing the array to the location you want. I would think if this is something you need to do repeatedly I would save a workbook with this code in it and use it like a template.

Here is some code that will allow you to load sheets from another workbook

```
Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook, CurrentWorkbook As Workbook 'sets up references to contain workbook information
Set CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook 'ThisWorkBook is a built in excel reference to the book the code is running on
Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("D:\file location\inputfile.xlsx") 'assigns the SourceWorkbook reference to the file location inside the quotes

SourceWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Main") 'this code takes the open file assigned to SourceWorkbook and copies "Sheet1" into the Workbook referenced by CurrentWorkbook (thisworkbook) after the sheet titled "Main" 
SourceWorkbook.Close 'closes the workbook you just imported data from
```

I recommend starting by importing all the data to a single workbook. Then if you need to reference something you will need to setup an array to collect the data with a looping function or by referencing the range directly. Here is a single loop reference example.

```
Dim RowCount as integer
Dim DataSortArray(1 To 1000, 1 To 3) As Variant
RowCount = 1
Do while currentworkbook.sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rowcount, 1) <> "" 
DataSortArray(RowCount, 1) = currentworkbook.sheets("sheet1")Cells(RowCount, 1) 
DataSortArray(RowCount, 2) = currentworkbook.sheets("sheet1")Cells(RowCount, 2) 
DataSortArray(RowCount, 3) = currentworkbook.sheets("sheet1")Cells(RowCount, 3) 
RowCount = RowCount + 1
loop
```

step by step it sets up variables for RowCount and DataSortArray. RowCount is set to 1 for the first record and is incremented by 1 each loop through to select the next record. Each cell location is set equal to the same location in DataSortArray which is used to store all the information. If you have many columns to collect I would recommend nesting a loop inside of another loop to collect the data. here is an example.

```
Dim RowCount as integer, ColCount as integer
Dim DataSortArray(1 To 1000, 1 To 3) As Variant
RowCount = 1
ColCount = 1
Do while currentworkbook.sheets("sheet1").Cells(RowCount, 1) <> ""

Do while ColCount < 4 
DataSortArray(RowCount, ColCount) = currentworkbook.sheets("sheet1")Cells(RowCount, ColCount) 

ColCount = ColCount + 1
loop
RowCount = RowCount + 1
ColCount = 1
loop
```

this is essentially the same code as above but with the flexibility of adding columns to the array easily by just changing the number it compares to. it will collect until column count is not less than 4 (so 3 columns per record) NOTE: you will need to increase your array size if you plan on getting more columns than 3 in my example. I.E. "Dim DataSortArray(1 To 1000, 1 To 10) As Variant" which would allow for 1000 records with 10 columns each.

once the array is populated with all of the data you want you can write it to a location

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).name = "Output" 'creates a new sheet called "Output" if you need to add a sheet
Sheets("Output").Range("a1:d10000").Value = DataSortArray 'prints out the finished array to the sheet titled "Output" again if you need more then 4 columns you will need to change the reference to be "Range("a1:j10000").Value" your range can be larger than needed but not smaller.
```

if you need to create a new file here is some code to do that.

```
Dim Fname as string

Fname = "C:\new.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Fname
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott. I will give it a try and will let you know if I have any questions. :)